# Huge React Form, Need to trigger validation from the form level, delegate to all children

Tags: reactjs

I am working for a software house, on our the first large scale React project. We are using React 17, everything is a function.

We have a form that comprises of a few hundred input fields. We are rendering this form using Material UI's TextField, KeyboardDatePicker, and Autocomplete components. This form handles presentation of XML messages that are exchanged between end points. There are 20 of these XML messages and many fields (and collections of fields) are common. For example, there is a field called MessageID that appears in all XML messages, and a field group called "Header" that comprises of a few fields like MessageID . MessageDateTime, MessageSender, etc.

So the first thing we did was to create UI components that encapsulate the presentation of these common components so that we can reuse then in all 20 messages. Also, we use custom hooks to do the validation, *on the component site*. This is to aid re-usability. Having the validation on the form level would mean that the component can't know how to validate itself.

So what we want to do is to trigger validation on the form level, delegate validation to all children, and if all goes well, submit the form.

The question is whether this is the "right" way to do it in react. And is this a react way of thinking? And if it is indeed an acceptable react pattern, what is the best way to do this?

We are asking since extensive google search on "trigger child validation react forms" doesn't bring back any meaningful results, in what I personally believe is a basic framework need, ie delegate validation to components and await for the results. Only react-hook-form offers something similar here https://react-hook-form.com/api/useform/trigger

Comment: This depends on the use case and the level of security that you would like the forms and its fields to have. For a simple website, a simple form validation should be enough like checking if the email has a valid email address, or if a phone number field actually has numbers in it. For larger projects, multiple level of validation (form and field validation) may be required and instead of doing it from scratch, you may want to look for existing libraries like https://formik.org/ that offers this kind of functionality.

Comment: Formik does NOT support delegation of validation on children input fields.